# Javascript count error

Tags: javascript, html

i created a javascript calculator and i used variables for everything but it won't work.
I tried to use `document.getElementById("box1").value` istead of just `v1` and i saw that something changed, i got `1111` if i type `11 + 11`, its different, why?
I don't know what is the problem, i tried a few things but nothing changed.

## Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>JS calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
 <input id="box1" type="text" placeholder="Number one" />
 <select name="" id="select">
  <option value="+">+</option>
  <option value="-">-</option>
  <option value="*">*</option>
  <option value="/">/</option>
 </select>
 <input id="box2" type="text" placeholder="Number two" />
 <button onclick="count()">Check</button>
 <a id="output"></a>
 <script>
 var v1 = document.getElementById("box1").value;
 var v2 = document.getElementById("box2").value;
 var sel = document.getElementById("select").value;
 var out = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
 function count() {
  if (sel === "+") {
   out = v1 + v2;
  }
  else if (sel === "-") {
   out = v1 - v2;
  }
  else if (sel === "*") {
   out = v1 * v2;
  }
  else if (sel === "/") {
   out = v1 / v2;
  }
  else {
   out = "Error Error Error!"
  }
 }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Hope I could make an anser. Anyway your problem is that your variables were getting initiated too early and it was getting wrong values once you click to check. Here is a fiddle so you can see things better https://jsfiddle.net/9pwb2yfe/ :)

Comment: Sorry, your question has been closed. There are several errors in your code. a) The code in the method count() cannot see the values entered by the user because the code that sets their value is executed immediately, before the user gets the chance to write something. b) The value returned by .innerHTML is just a value, it is not something that you can update. You need to set the innerHTML on the HTML element document.getElementById().innerHTML = calc; c) The values that you read from .innerHTML are strings and so a sum will calculate the concatenation of the strings and not what you wanted.

Comment: @BipBip you can answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 problems in your script.

First you should get element values inside the count() function (because you want to read those values each time someone clicks the check button).

Second, you shouldn't read the output value but write it instead.

Third, you must cast your input values to int to avoid things like: 1 + 1 = 11.

```
function count() {
  var v1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("box1").value);
  var v2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("box2").value);
  var sel = document.getElementById("select").value;
  var out;
  if (sel === "+") {
    out = v1 + v2;
  } else if (sel === "-") {
    out = v1 - v2;
  } else if (sel === "*") {
    out = v1 * v2;
  } else if (sel === "/") {
    out = v1 / v2;
  } else {
    out = "Error Error Error!"
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = out;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle with an example solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpw7zr8o)

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your code.

a) The code in the method count() cannot see the values entered by the user because the code that sets their value is executed immediately, before the user gets the chance to write something.

b) The value returned by .innerHTML is just a value, it is not something that you can update. You need to set the innerHTML on the HTML element

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = out;
```

c) The values that you read from .innerHTML are strings and so a sum will calculate the concatenation of the strings and not what you wanted. The multiplication will not work at all.

Answer (score 1):

There were multiple issues with you code:

- You have to assign `v1`, `v2` and `sel` in `count()` or they will be only set once at page load
- The variable `out` is overwritten in your code. You should assign it like this:

`var out = document.getElementById("output");`

`out.innerHTML = "foo";`

- You have to cast your input values from string to int using `parseInt()`

You can find a JSBin here: http://jsbin.com/hotoletore/edit?html,js,output

Good luck with you calculator :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function count() {
    var v1 = document.getElementById("box1").value;
    var v2 = document.getElementById("box2").value;
    var sel = document.getElementById("select").value;
    if (sel === "+") {
         document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = +v1 + +v2;
    }
    else if (sel === "-") {
         document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = parseInt(v1 - v2);
    }
    else if (sel === "*") {
         document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = parseInt(v1 * v2);
    }
    else if (sel === "/") {
         document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = parseInt(v1 / v2);
    }
    else {
         document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Error Error Error!"
    }
}
```

If you put `v1` , `v2`, `sel` before the `count()` function, they are initiating with initial values meaning empty, empty and +.

And you have to parse to integers the output with `parseInt`.

Note that `+v1` casts the string to int directly.

https://jsfiddle.net/9pwb2yfe/

Comment: Why are you using the unary `+` to convert the inputs to numbers but `parseInt` three times to _re-parse_ values that are _already_ numbers?! The way you “fixed” the code doesn’t make much sense.